# How to select another column in table if first column doesnt have value that i need

Tags: sql, select, lead

I have 1 table where is 2 columns that i need to use at this moment( length and length_to_fault). If length has a null(N/A) value then i need to select value from length_to_fault and opposite.
I also need to sort everything and i can do it with 1 column like this:

`select d.* from (select d.*, lead(length::float) over (partition by port_nbr, pair order by add_date) as next_length from diags d where length != 'N/A') d`

this select sorts everything except length_to_fault. If 1 record has value in length_to_fault , it will be ignored and it wont show up.
Is there any suggestions?
Maybe its possible to just make these 2 columns into 1? It sounds much logical. But how?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: you can try that with Coalesce.

Comment: I'm rather baffled.  I think your `lead()` should generate a type conversion error when the next value is `'N/A'`.  Also you mention "sorting" but your question has no `order by`.  And there is no column in the query called `length_to_fault`.

Comment: There is length_to_fault in my table, but i dont know how to use it in my code. Everything works as i need it , but with only length. There is 1 problem : There is 2 columns - length and length_to_fault. If length is N/A, then length_to_fault has a value. And if length_to_fault is N/A, then length has value. I could just combine these 2 columns into 1 , but i dont know how

Answer (score 1):

I changed it to  `select d.* from (select d.*, lead(sum(length::float + length_to_fault::float)) over (partition by port_nbr, pair order by d.add_date) as next_length from diags d)d`
i get error : column "d.ip" must appear in the group by clause or be used in an aggregate function.
I dont need to use ip column... I even dont know where to put that ip right now